# Kubernetes Jobs not running

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using GKE and I'm facing a strange problem with k8s jobs.
When i create a new job i got the status created but no pods run for this job so the job pod status still 0 running, 0 success, 0 fail

Note: It was working before and suddenly stopped to work

Answer (score 3):

Very little to go by from your description, but use `kubectl describe jobs/[name]` and `kubectl logs` to investigate further.

Comment: I now but already i have a little to debug no pods running for this job to can debug

Comment: Describe job should show you the latest events which may provide you some answers as to why there are no pods, such as if the pods are unschedulable

Comment: You may also share the output of `kubectl describe jobs` for some answers; ensure to redact anything in the log that you may not want to share.